# how to get a required data format from yahoo finance API using flask, it is confusing me

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I need this data *(NIO Inc. NIO 21.05 -0.29257 77123545 68510787 99146121216
)* as an output of my flask web app in a Json format.

my expecting output image is given as a link - [also required data's are in yellow boxed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHWLO.png)

(Or)

You can guide me how to get these below mentioned output as an flask web API format. Also, fine for me to proceed next step.

```
import yfinance as yf
stocks = yf.Ticker("NIO")
a = stocks.info['shortName']
b = stocks.info['symbol']
c = stocks.info['currentPrice']
d = stocks.info['profitMargins']
e = stocks.info['volume']
f = stocks.info['averageVolume']
g = stocks.info['marketCap']
#h = stocks.info['trailingPE']
print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
```

> Output - NIO Inc. NIO 21.05 -0.29257 77123545 68510787 99146121216

But, i actually get an complete info as a json format, need any one guidance.

app.py

```
# importing Flask and other modules
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import yfinance as yf
# Flask constructor
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/info/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def display_quote():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # getting input text in HTML form
        text = request.form['text']
    
        symbol = request.args.get('symbol', text)

        quote = yf.Ticker(symbol)

        return quote.info
    return render_template("form.html")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

templates/form.html

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just to create a dict with your information you want and return that in the flask view

```
quote = yf.Ticker(symbol)
return {
   "a": quote.info['shortName'],
   "b": quote.info['symbol'],
   "c": quote.info['currentPrice'],
   "d": quote.info['profitMargins'],
   "e": quote.info['volume'],
   "f": quote.info['averageVolume'],
   "g": quote.info['marketCap'],
}
```

This gives you a json repsonse on the flask route